Jabx XML need two different prefixes for same namespace
I need to parse a Java class into a XML.
The xml should have different prefixes for the same namespace, like this:
<ns0:partOne xmlns:ns0="http://test.com">
   <ns0:partTwo xmlns:ns1="http://test.com" >
     <ns1:partThree />   
   </ns0:partTwo>
</ns0:partOne>

--package -> com.pk
class PartOne { private PartTwo partTwo}

package-info
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://test.com",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns={
                @XmlNs(prefix="ns0", namespaceURI="http://test.com")
        }
)

--package -> com.pp
class PartTwo {
 private List<PartThree> list;
}

package-info
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://test.com",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns={
                @XmlNs(prefix="ns1", namespaceURI="http://test.com")
        }
)

But the XML I get is:
<ns1:partOne xmlns:ns0="http://test.com">
   <ns1:partTwo xmlns:ns1="http://test.com" >
     <ns1:partThree />   
   </ns1:partTwo>
</ns1:partOne>

How can I have different prefixes in this case?

Why do you want to do this? You shouldn't care about prefixes. Any sensible XML consuming application isn't going to care about prefixes - it's only the namespace URI that matters.
